# Couldnot get dat from Fragment B to Fragment A

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

i have dynamic tab in fragment A and weview in it.When the content of dynamic  tab is clicked i want to open the link in the same page in webview.
[image]

i tried using interface but it didnt help me.Here is my code

Setup Dynamic TabBar

```
    NewsFragment fView;

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager, List<Datum> data) {

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());

        for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++){
            fView = new NewsFragment().newInstance(data.get(i).getSlug());
            adapter.addFrag(fView,data.get(i).getName(),data.get(i).getSlug());

        }

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

I tried to call the data here using interface listener but it returns null

```
fView.OnNewsClickedListener(link -> {
            Log.e("asdasdas",link);
        });
```

My Fragment With Tabs

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    OnNews onNews;

    RestManager restManager = new RestManager();
    Myinterface myinterface = restManager.getMyinterface();
    NewsAdapter newsAdapter;

    public static NewsFragment newInstance(String item) {
        NewsFragment fragment = new NewsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("slug", item);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            apiResponse(getArguments().getString("slug"));
        }
    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyler_newslist);
        newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
        newsAdapter.OnPostListener(link -> {
                        onNews.onClicked(link);

        });

        return view.getRootView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    private void apiResponse(String slug) {

        Call<PostResponse> call = myinterface.getAllNews(slug);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<PostResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PostResponse> call, Response<PostResponse> response) {

                if (response.body().getStatus()) {
                    Log.e("asdsdasd",new Gson().toJson(response.body().getData()));
                    newsAdapter.setNews(response.body().getData());
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PostResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }

    public  interface OnNews{
        void onClicked(String link);
    }

    public  void OnNewsClickedListener(OnNews onNews){
        this.onNews = onNews;
    }
}
```